# Simple Me.Refresh results not as expected

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image]
I have a form Frm_tbl_Cruise_Form with cruise details (see above).  The data source for this form is a table called dbo_tbl_CruiseInformation.  The form, when I create a new cruise accepts some data and then adds a new record and sets fields including the key field CruiseID, which is formed from the fields.  A button on the form called Set Cruise ID runs the following code:

```
Private Sub CreateCruise_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim crs As Recordset
Dim shp As Recordset
Dim legstring As String
Dim vessel As String
Dim year As String
Dim crsnum As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set crs = db.OpenRecordset("dbo_tbl_CruiseInformation", dbOpenDynaset)
Set shp = db.OpenRecordset("dbo_tlu_NoaaShips", dbOpenDynaset)

If IsNull(Leg) Then
    legstring = ""
Else
    legstring = "L" & Format(Leg, "0")
End If

shp.FindFirst ("[ID] = " & Vessel_Used)
vessel = shp!ShipCode
year = Format(Me!Date_Start, "YY")
crsnum = Format(Me!VesselNumber, "00")

crs.AddNew
crs!CruiseID = vessel & year & crsnum & legstring
crs!Vessel_Used = Me!Vessel_Used
crs!VesselNumber = crsnum
crs!Date_Start = Me!Date_Start
crs.Update

Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

But I get an error on the Me.Refresh that states "You must enter a value in the 'dbo_tbl_CruiseInformation.CruiseID' field.

Aren't I doing that?  If I replace the Me.Refresh with Me!CruiseID = vessel & year & crsnum & legstring it fills it in the top of the form, but I am just befuddled as to why?

Comment: You're doing a strange mixture of bound form vs. unbound controls (?) and editing the table behind the form. This does not work well. Try sticking to the bound form as far as possible and use the automatic functionality that Access gives you.

Comment: oh, I see.  I'm making it more difficult than it needs to be!  I took out the AddNew and everything below and just set Me!CruiseID to what I need.  Thanks @Andre!